# Jupyter Notebook: plt.annotate().draggable() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, annotations

I am trying to use the `plt.annotate().draggable()`.

I tested it on a sample code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.annotate('my annotation', xy=(3,4), textcoords='data').draggable()
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, it is not working in Jupyter Notebook.

When the plot is created, the annotation is not interactable, so I can't drag it.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`widget`](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) backend.

You may install it from console:

```
activate base
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
```

Then in Jupyter Notebook **restart the kernel** and add a magic command

```
%matplotlib widget
```

to the start:

```
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.annotate('my annotation', xy=(3,4), textcoords='data').draggable()
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
```

(The `plt.show()` command is not needed.)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but where is this console? Is it Anacondas Prompt?

Comment: So I found the console, but the command is not recognized. `activate base` shows invalid syntax. `conda install -c conda-forge ipympl` shows "incomplete escape".

I ended up using `pip` install for `ipympl`, and restarted the kernal. But now all my plot shows javascript error.

Comment: It is probably more informative to call it `ipympl` these days as that is the name of the package and the repo and `%matplotlib ipympl` is more abundant in the documentation now , see [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example), which `widget` just mentioned in passing.

Comment: `ipympl` is a complex install because it involves a lot of changes. You need to restart everything involved, jupyter and browser, not just just the kernel. At least refresh the browser if not restarting it. And if you use Anaconda/conda, then you chose that as your primary package manager and should endeavor to always use it. Resorting to `pip` as a last resort only. You'll only put off issues until later and have non-robust and not portable environments, generally.

Comment: So I got the widget working. But for some reason all my plots now are overlapping with each other... Multiple set of data showing up in the same plot, which isn't what I originally had.

Comment: That is probably a different post then because you resolved your titular issue it seems? 'all my plots now are overlapping'? You only show one in the post.

Comment: @Wayne That was a sample code. I will play around widget a little and see if I can solve that issue, but you are right it should be a different post. Thank you for the help!